# FreeBuilder library in Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, builder-pattern, android-gradle-2.0

I'm trying to use FreeBuilder library. It is a library for the implementation of the Builder design pattern. When I build the project no error are shown and the project is build successfully, but I connot run it because of some errors on generated files. Android studio, however, doesn't recognize generated builder and the methods of the builder. I'm trying the example on the README of the library page.

Comment: You could try to use the following approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107571/freebuilder-in-an-android-studio-java-module