# FreeBuilder in an Android Studio Java module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, builder, auto-value

I want to use [FreeBuilder](https://github.com/google/FreeBuilder) in a Java module in Android Studio. I added the following dependency in the module dependencies:

```
compile 'org.inferred:freebuilder:1.10.5'
```

Then I created the following class:

```
@FreeBuilder
public abstract class MyClass {

    public abstract String getValue1();

    public abstract String getValue2();

    public abstract String getValue3();

    public static class Builder extends MyClass_Builder {
    }
}
```

I can see that the MyClass_Builder class is correctly generated in the build/classes/main folder and the build is done successfully.

The problem is that the Android Studio does not find this class and therefore it marks it as an error.

How can I make Android Studio see the automatically generated class?

If I configure the module as an Android library module, the generated classes are detected by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround solution is to add the following line to the module build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'build/libs')
```

It is not a perfect solution, because a clean and build must be done every time a change is done on any class that uses the FreeBuilder.